# Formatting Sum of negative value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I am creating a report in SSRS. I want to sum a column and  change the color to red if value goes to negative. But my expression is not working. Here is my expression.

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Column.Value) < 0, "Red", "Black")
```

Comment: "but my expression is not working" . Can you add more ? How it is not working ? Your statement seems correct for me.

Comment: suppose the SUM(column) returned me -19. so this expression returning me "Red" in output. instead of changing the color of value(-19) to red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the expression in the font color and not the cell value.

To do this : right click on the cell you want the font color to change - text box properties - Font - click on the Fx next to the color and then place the expression

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Column.Value) < 0, "Red", "Black")
```

This will change the font color based on it's value